# How to get server side includes to work on Apache which is installed on Centros 7?

Tags: apache, centos7, ssi

I have ssi working on InMotionHosting but can not get it to work on a local Centros 7 install.
Apache version 2.4.6

The httpd -M  shows that the so_module is loaded but not the mod_include.

When I tried to add mod_include I get the error:
`httpd: Syntax error on line 55 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure`mod_include' in file /etc/httpd/modules/mod_include.so: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_include.so: undefined symbol: mod_include'

I tried to modify the httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Options +Includes
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

Still the SSI fails.

The index file is simple:

```
<h1>Test page</h1>
/var/www/index.html
<br/>
<!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->
<!--#include virtual="./insert.shtml" -->
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Got ssi to work on Centros 8 by setting XBitHack on.

httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Options +Includes
    # AddType text/html .shtml
    # AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
    XBitHack on
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And in the /var/www/html do:

```
chmod +x test.shml
```

index.htm:

> <!--#include file="test.shtml" -->

Now .shtml files can be used.

Server version: Apache/2.4.37 (centos)

Answer (score 0):

After a few more flops, I found this to work:

> AddType text/html .shtml
>
> AddHandler server-parsed .html

All the examples that I found showed AddHandler server-parsed .shtml. My main file is index.html and the ssi file is test.shtml.

Hope this has helped someone.